# I want to fade out a record after deleting that using ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax

This is the ajax code I have used. But it doesn't work. I want to fade out a record after deleting it so that the user can see its deleted without refreshing the page. Its really great if someone can help me. Thanks inadvance

```
function delete_item(item_id){
    var item = item_id;
    var temp = "#" + item_id;
    var temp1 = "'" + temp + "'";

    if(confirm("Sure you want to delete this update? There is NO undo!")){
        $.ajax({
            url : 'DeleteItem.php',
            method : 'POST',
            data : { item: item },
            success : function(){
                $(temp).html(result);
            }      
        });
        $(this).parents("tr").animate({ backgroundColor: "#003" },"slow").animate({ opacity: "hide" }, "slow");
    }         
}
```

Comment: Put the animation into `success` callback. Save `this` before calling `$.ajax`: `var self = this;`, and use `self` within the callback.

Comment: `success : function(){$(this).parents("tr").animate({ backgroundColor: "#003" }, "slow").animate({ opacity: "hide" }, "slow");}`

Comment: *"This is the ajax code I have used. But it doesn't work."* - What doesn't work, the ajax call or the hiding of the element? You've put your `.animate()` code *outside* the `if` block, which doesn't make sense.

Comment: This is not a PHP question; please don't use irrelevant tags.

Answer (score 0):

For every ajax request you make, always determine if it succeeded before doing the animation of what you really want to do. Try to learn also `json_encode` in your server side to get a better result for your success function

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function delete_item(item_id){
            var item = item_id;
            var temp = "#"+item_id;
            var temp1 = "'"+temp+"'";
            if(confirm("Sure you want to delete this update? There is NO undo!")){
                $.ajax({
                    url : 'DeleteItem.php',
                    method : 'POST',
                    data : {item:item},
                    success : function(){
                        $(temp).html(result);
                        $(this).parents("tr").animate({ backgroundColor: "#003" }, "slow").animate({ opacity: "hide" }, "slow");
                }
            });
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: i tried the above way but still it does not fade away . Do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: okay, my suggestion is try the simplest way and make it work first before applying a complex one. `$(this).parents("tr").remove();` try first this if your element has been removed. if not then you're the selector is your problem. show your elements sample for us to check if the selector your trying to remove is correct

Comment: oh, i think your problem here is the `this` of `$(this).parents("tr")`. try to console the `this` in success and it will show what is `this` really

Comment: its removed when I refresh the page. I wanted to remove the row at the time I click the delete button, without refreshing the page. So any suggestions to make it fade away??

Comment: not doing what you told so cant help you in anyway.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function delete_item(item_id){
        var item = item_id;
        var temp = "#"+item_id;
        var temp1 = "'"+temp+"'";
        if(confirm("Sure you want to delete this update? There is NO undo!")){
            $.ajax({
                url : 'DeleteItem.php',
                method : 'POST',
                data : {item:item},
                success : function(){
                    $(temp).fadeOut('fast', function(){
                           // function called after fadeout completes
                           // fadeOut does the animation you want.
                           // you can obtain ID before saving it as a variable
                    }),
                statusCode: {
                    200: function(){
                         // you can put the fadeOut code in here, as this guarantees that when the server responds accordingly you will then run your code, you can also set functions for other response codes.
                       }

                 }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried this approach. This did not solve my problem